# getting an empty string with json_encode()

Tags: php, json

See attached code. for some reason the `json_encode()` is returning an empty string.
I call it by using `$jv = Video::ConvertToJson($video);`
Using breakpoints I verified that `$video` wasn't null, etc.
(using PHP 5.3)
Any ideas?
thx

```
class Video
{
    private $ID;
    private $Title;
    private $ViewCount;
    private $Description;
    private $IsEmbeddable;
    private $IsPrivate;

    function __construct($id = 0, $title = '', $viewcount=0, $description='', $isembeddable=1, $isprivate=0){
        $this->ID = $id;
        $this->Title = $title;
        $this->ViewCount = $viewcount;
        $this->Description = $description;
        $this->IsEmbeddable = $isembeddable;
        $this->IsPrivate = $isprivate;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Converts a Tfyoutubevideo into a json object
     * @param models\TfYoutubevideos $tfv
     */
     public static function ConvertToJson(models\TfYoutubevideos $tfv){
        $v = new Video();
        $v->ID = $tfv->getId();
        $v->Title = $tfv->getVideotitle();
        $v->ViewCount = $tfv->getVideoviewcount();
        $v->Description = $tfv->getVideoDescription();
        $v->IsEmbeddable = $tfv->getVideoIsEmbeddable();
        $v->IsPrivate = $tfv->getVideoIsPrivate();
        $vj = json_encode($v);
        return $vj;

     }
}
```

Comment: `ConvertToJson(models\TfYoutubevideos $tfv){` ← this looks strange to me. what if you drop the `models\TfYoutubevideos`?

Comment: @knittl It's a type specification, and the type is in a namespace. It looks strange, but that's because those are features new to php 5.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json_encode` does not serialize private (or protected) member variables. Either copy your object's state into a temporary array or declare member variables as public to mitigate that.

Comment: "copy your object's state into a temporary array" - please can you tell me how?

Comment: Implement `ConvertToJson` like `return json_encode(["ID" => $tfv->getId(), 'Title' => $tfv->getVideotitle()]);`